# Computing offset curve with Teigha 4.1.1

Tags: c++, teigha

I am struggling with computing a parallel line to the existing line in certain distance.

I have tried:
`OdGeLine2d::getTrimmedOffset()`
`OdGeLineSeg2d::getTrimmedOffset()`
`OdGeLine3d::getTrimmedOffset()`
`OdGeLineSeg3d::getTrimmedOffset()`

but all of them trow a **"Not implemented"** exception.

Than I tried to use a `OdGeOffsetCurve2d` class. Constructing of this class doesn't throw exception, but any attempt to get a point of this curve does. Same exception: "Not implemented".

So, *how can a get a point that lies on the* `OdGeOffsetCurve2d` ? Or is there any other way to compute an offset curve?

And what are all those `getTrimmedOffset()` methods for? Just to throw exceptions?

---

PS: I do not have enough reputation to create a new **Teigha** tag. Please, do so and edit my question. Teigha is a core library for developing CAD applications https://www.opendesign.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly you are trying to create a parallel line to an already existing line.

If you not specifically looking for OdGeLine2d , i have a solution for similar problem with OdDbLine.
As you already know , to construct a new line if we have its end points rest is play.
 So I will help you find end Points of Parallel Line with OdDbLine Class.
You can try to derive from it.
My code is the .Net version code and not the c++ one.

If you have and object of `OdDbLine` Class lets say `OdDbLine line`

a) Get its End Points

`OdGePoint3d startPoint = new OdGePoint3d();
line.getStartPoint(startPoint);`
`OdGePoint3d endPoint = new OdGePoint3d();
line.getEndPoint(endPoint);`

Get the line direction, use it to compute perpendicular direction
 
`OdGeVector3d lineVector = GetLineVector(line);
OdGeVector3d perpendicularVec = lineVector.perpVector();                   perpendicularVec.normalize();
perpendicularVec = perpendicularVec.Mul(-1);`

OffSet the Line End Points to calculated offset end points
Offset value is the numerical distance from your current line 
`perpendicularVec.setToProduct(perpendicularVec, offSetValue);`

Calculated new End Points Point at Offset Location
`OdGePoint3d newOffsetStartPt = startPoint.Add(perpendicularVec);
OdGePoint3d newOffsetEndPt = endPoint.Add(perpendicularVec);`

You can use the new endpoints to construct a new Line.

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Thanks! Great to see a Teigha expert here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a shorter way to make an offset curve for a linear entity. You can make a copy of your line and move it (transform it) to a nessesary distance. Like this:

```
OdGeLine2d ln(OdGePoint2d::kOrigin, OdGeVector2d::kXAxis);
const double dOffsetDistance = 100.0;

OdGeVector2d vOffset = ln.direction().perpVector(); //ccw rotation
vOffset.normalize();
vOffset *= dOffsetDistance;

ln.transformBy( OdGeMatrix2d::translation(vOffset) );
```